# Send some parameters to the same page using jquery.ajax

Tags: jquery

hi folks
I use jquery and it gives me error : "Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'url' is null or not an object"
when I use "$.ajax(window.location.href");" inside window.location.href is like this :
 "http://localaddress/mypage.aspx?id=2"
How I can solve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) takes an object with options, like this:

```
$.ajax({ url: window.location.href });
```

If you just want to fetch a URL, use [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) like this:

```
$.get(window.location.href);
```

It's one of the [`$.ajax()` shorthand methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/shorthand-methods/), if you want to send parameters, it looks like this:

```
$.get("mypage.aspx", { id: 2 });
//or long-hand
$.ajax({ url: "mypage.aspx", data: { id: 2 }});
```